# Binding RowCommand to fire when any cell in a row is clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, selectedindexchanged

My GridView basically displays a summarized version of data in the database.

What I want to do is set it up so that when you click anywhere in a row in the GridView, it should execute a set procedure that'll hide the panel that contains the GridView and display a panel that will show you the details of the item you clicked.

```
        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlList">
            <div class="rightalign">
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblCount"></asp:Label>
            </div>

            <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvItems" DataKeyNames="mailid" 
                AutoGenerateColumns="false" onrowdatabound="gvItems_RowDataBound" 
                Width="100%" OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvItems_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkSelect" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblStatus" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "status") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="firstname" HeaderText="From" SortExpression="firstname" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="datesent" HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="datesent" DataFormatString="{0:yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm}" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="subject" HeaderText="Subject" SortExpression="subject" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        </asp:Panel>

        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlMail">
            <p>From: <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblFrom"></asp:Label><br />
                Sent On: <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblDate"></asp:Label><br />
                Subject: <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblSubject"></asp:Label></p>
            <p><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblMessage"></asp:Label></p>
        </asp:Panel>
```

I figured I'd use the `SelectedIndexChanged` event, but I'm not sure how to actually make it fire off clicks on the cells.

Here's the code I've got:

```
    protected void gvItems_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int index = gvItems.SelectedIndex;

        string mailid = gvItems.DataKeys[index].Value.ToString();

        getMailDetail(mailid);
        pnlMail.Visible = true;
    }

    protected void getMailDetail(string id)
    {
        int mailid = int.Parse(id);
        MySqlContext db = new MySqlContext();

        string sql = "select m.datesent, m.subject, m.message, u.firstname, u.lastname from mail m inner join users u on m.senderid = u.userid where m.mailid = @id";

        List<MySqlParameter> args = new List<MySqlParameter>();
        args.Add(new MySqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@id", MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.Int32, Value = mailid });

        MySqlDataReader dr = db.getReader(sql, args);

        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            dr.Read();

            lblFrom.Text = (string)dr["firstname"] + " " + (string)dr["lastname"];
            lblDate.Text = (string)dr["datesent"];
            lblSubject.Text = (string)dr["subject"];
            lblMessage.Text = (string)dr["message"];
        }
        dr.Close();
    }
```

How can I make clicks on the cells in a row fire an event that'll do the work I need done?

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can see two possible solutions here. First - handle click on the row on client side, send Ajax request to some `HttpHandler` that will return you necessary mail details, and display the returned info. Steps to achieve this:

Assign a client side handler too row click:

```
protected void gvItems_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Attributes["onClick"] = "showMailDetails(" + DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "id") + ")";
    }
}
```

And define the client side function:

```
function showMailDetails(mailId) {
    $.get(
        url: 'url to HttpHandler here',
        data: {id: mailId},
        success: function(data) {
            var pnlMail = $('#<%= pnlMail.ClientID %>');
            // display data here

            pnlMail.show()
    });   
}
```

Another way is to handle click on client side and then emulate `RowCommand` event by doing something like this:

```
protected void gvItems_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Attributes["onClick"] = ""javascript:__doPostBack('" + gvItems.ClientID + "','MailDetailsCommand$" + DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "id") + "')";
    }
}
```

And then on server side go like you already did, just in RowComamnd handler:

```
protected void gvItems_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "MailDetailsCommand") {
    // ...
    }
}
```

Although I would not recommend this method - using `_doPostBack` manully is not considered as a best practice.

Comment: Can you clarify a bit on the url for the HttpHandler? Not sure what's supposed to go there

Comment: @Ortund, url to some server side method that returns necessary information in, say, JSON format. You can implement it as a WebMethod on the page, or a separate HttpHandler how I suggested - doesn't matter.

Comment: Right, well... I haven't got this working just yet, but that's being dealt with on another question. Gonna accept this answer as I'm using your first suggested solution

Answer (score 1):

you give a template field which consist the button or a button field and then you can the give the commandname as something and then you can use the gridview commandeventargs and based on the commandname you can do whatever you want, and you can use the OnRowCommand  to fire an event :D hope this will help you .....

You can even go for adding the onclick attribute to the cell in the RowDataBound Event, if there are any restrictions of not having the button field or like that

Comment: You're saying I should set every column to a template column and set it all do the same thing on RowCommand?

Comment: No need to do like that add another column which consists of the button field or a template field with button then on click of the respective button you can get the data of the particular row which you clicked and then you can do the manipulation you want later

Comment: So the user will have to specifically click the button to read the details for the item... That's how I normally do it, but it does tend to make the GridView look "clunky" I think. Kinda going for a bit more streamlined here

Comment: so if you want to do without using the button field and get the click event for individual cell then you can go for adding the
 onclick attribute to the cell in the RowDataBound Event

Comment: right, I'm setting the attribute, but my browser is telling me that getMailDetail is undefined because getMailDetail does not exist on the client... it's a server call